# Proximal Gradient of absolute value of linear function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, proximal-operators

I am working through

https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2013/26/article.pdf

This is an attempt at simplyfying deriving (13) from (9).

One of the posed problems can be written as,

\begin{equation}
\min_{\textbf{v}} \frac{1}{2}||\textbf{v} - \textbf{u}||_2^2 + |\textbf{y}\cdot (\textbf{v} - \textbf{x}) + c|
\end{equation}

Where $\textbf{y}$, $\textbf{x}$, and $c$ are fixed.

Taking the gradient, I get the set of equations:

\begin{equation}
0 =
    \begin{cases}
      \textbf{v} - \textbf{u} - \textbf{y} & \rho(\textbf{v}) < 0\\
      [\textbf{v} - \textbf{u} - \textbf{y}, \textbf{v} - \textbf{u} + \textbf{y}] &  \rho(\textbf{v}) = 0\\
      \textbf{v} - \textbf{u} + \textbf{y} &  \rho(\textbf{v}) > 0
    \end{cases}   
\end{equation}
where
$$\rho(\textbf{v}) := |\textbf{y}\cdot (\textbf{v} - \textbf{x}) + c|$$

this is where I get stuck.

I arrive at this inequality

\begin{equation}
\min(\textbf{v} - \textbf{u} - \textbf{y}, \textbf{v} - \textbf{u} + \textbf{y}) \le 0 \le \max(\textbf{v} - \textbf{u} - \textbf{y}, \textbf{v} - \textbf{u} + \textbf{y})
\end{equation}

where min and max are done element wise, e.g.

\begin{equation}
\min(v_i - u_i - y_i, v_i - u_i + y_i) \le 0 \le \max(v_i - u_i - y_i, v_i - u_i + y_i)
\end{equation}

Intuitively, $\text{v} = \textbf{u} + \lambda \textbf{y}$, where $\lambda \in [-1, 1]$.  However, I am getting stuck working with the constraint $\rho(\textbf{v}) = 0$ which leads to

$$\lambda  = -\rho(\textbf{v})\frac{\textbf{y}}{||\textbf{y}||_2^2} $$

Comment: Use `\min` and `\max` instead.

Comment: To clarify, from (9), u is also fixed and the $L^2$ norm is integration.  $\rho(v)$ should not have absolute value signs or else it is never negative.

Comment: What does the notation $[\textbf{v} - \textbf{u} - \textbf{y}, \textbf{v} - \textbf{u} + \textbf{y}]$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

the initial problem with the absolute value can be reformulated into a smooth constrained problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{\textbf{v}} & \frac{1}{2}||\textbf{v} - \textbf{u}||_2^2 + p + n \\
s.t. & \quad \textbf{y}\cdot (\textbf{v} - \textbf{x}) + c = p - n \\
     & \quad p, n \ge 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $p$ and $n$ capture the positive and negative part of $\textbf{y}\cdot (\textbf{v} - \textbf{x}) + c$, respectively. You can then tackle this problem using constrained optimization methods.